# Automate detecting schema differences between TFS and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tfs, continuous-integration

Our reporting team uses TFS for Stored Procedure version control (only sprocs).
We need to have an automated way to compare what's in TFS and SQL Server to remind developers to check in their code whenever differences found. I've tried using the TFS Build and publish to another database, thinking I could use system tables to do the content compare, but was unsuccessful with deployment. Has anyone had to setup anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [a database project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193245(v=vs.140).aspx) containing the Stored Procedures, you can use [SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in the build to generate a XML deploy report that shows you the changes.